# How to avoid duplicate Cursor.Current statement?

Tags: c#, error-handling, cursor, try-catch-finally

If I am turning on the `WaitCursor` before a processing task and then turning it back to default, I often get this pattern of code:

```
try {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    MyProcessingTask();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
finally { Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; }
```

I need to have the `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` in the `catch` block so that the `MessageBox` is given a default cursor to use.

Is there a better way to write this code without having to write two `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` statements?

Comment: You could remove the finally block and have the `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;` statement after the `MyProcessingTask();` call; otherwise I think you're stuck with having it twice.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `try ... finally` statement into the `try` block of the `try ... catch` statement?

Comment: @Tim: If I put it after `MyProcessingTask();`, then if an exception is raised by `MyProcessingTask()` I will still need to have it also in the `catch` block, won't I?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: can you elaborate?

Comment: @CJ7: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: @CJ7 - Yes.  I didn't say remove it from your catch block; I simply said you could get rid of the finally block :)

Comment: @Tim: This is not directed to me, is it? :-S

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - No, I put in the wrong user name initially.  I edited the comment. Sorry for any confusion or misdirected comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a disposable class and exploit the `using` syntact-sugar, i.e. :

```
class WaitingCursor : IDisposable
{
    public WaitingCursor()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
try
{
    using (var wcurs = new WaitingCursor())
    {
        MyProcessingTask();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The OP's concern is changing the cursor back *before* showing the message box, which isn't done by this solution.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: actually, when the MessageBox appears it doesn't show the waitcursor...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: however, inverting the using with the try catch you will get the desired result (edited).

Comment: I didn't try; I just went by the OP's statement *I need to have the Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; in the catch block so that the MessageBox is given a default cursor to use.*; maybe the sample code was accidentally oversimplified (non-standard message box, for example). Anyway, your edited solution is indeed valid.

Answer (score 1):

You could nest a `try`/`finally` block inside a `try`/`catch` block:

```
try {
    try {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        MyProcessingTask();
    }
    finally { Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Whether this is *better* or not may be subject to opinion. It reduces some code duplication, but it doesn't (to my eyes) have a "familiar" look to it. Someone may see this in 6 months time and refactor it back into the familiar `try`/`catch`/`finally` structure (and lose the cursor change in the `catch` block).

---

By the way - the general pattern of catching *all* exceptions at this low level is generally frowned upon. By "handling" every possible exception by just displaying the `Message`, you're losing potential debugging help. I would usually recommend that a) You only handle *specific* exceptions that your code actually has a sensible strategy for dealing with, and b) Letting all other exceptions propogate out to a top-level exception handler that a) Might display a message, but b) Also logs all relevant parts of the exception, including call stacks, etc.

Swallowing the exception (as here) can mean that the application isn't in a fit state to continue running, but will attempt to do so. Making the final crash (if it happens) far more difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Will the outer `catch` block handle an exception thrown by `MyProcessingTask()`?

Comment: @CJ7: Yes, it will. The `finally` block doesn't catch the exception, `finally` just means it's executed even when control-flow otherwise jumps out of the current block (e.g. also when a `return` statement is within the `try` block of a `try ... finally` statement).

Comment: @CJ7 - Yes. When an exception occurs, it propogates out from the point at which it's thrown until a matching `catch` clause is found. That `catch` clause could be anywhere - in the same method, or in any method in the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
        Exception exception = null;
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            MyProcessingTask();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        if (exception!= null)
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
```

Even though this seems like a plausable solution, I would rather recomend keeping the double cursor setting as I would prefer that all exception logic be handled inside the Catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Nest a `try ... finally` statement in the `try` block of your existing `try ... catch` statement like this:

```
try {
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try {
        MyProcessingTask();
    }
    finally {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by extension method:

```
static void ProcessWithWaitCursor(this Action task)
{
    try {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        task();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally { Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default; }
```

}

then just use it like this:

```
MyProcessingTask.ProcessWithWaitCursor()
```

This will eliminate all repeated code from all places where you want to do this.

Comment: I believe OP is trying to eliminate having the same two lines of code in the try/catch - which this solution doesn't.

Comment: You are right but the idea is to write less and do the same thing this answer is providing a way to not worry about **Cursor** at all. What does he gain by eliminating one line? One times all places where he uses this construction in term or lines of code. My solution reduces code to single line. So I think it is relevant.